# Command works in console, not in code

Tags: c#, process

Just killed 5 hours on this, giving up for the moment.

This command works fine from a non-elevated command prompt (Permissions pregranted on the key so no issues):

```
REG ADD "HKCR\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolder" /v Attributes /d 0xA0900100 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

But the c# version doesn't produce any changes to the regkey: (Same machine as above with same regkey permissions incase anyone asks):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD", "/C REG ADD \"HKCR\\CLSID\\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\\ShellFolder\" /v Attributes /d 0xA0900100 /t REG_DWORD /f");
```

I've tried several variations, none of them work. 3 other developers I deal with are baffled the command doesn't work, and nobody can figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried capturing the standard output and standard error streams to see if any errors are being written by the `reg` command?

Comment: What is the reason you are using process start instead of making use of the .NET Registry class?

Comment: Why are you having your program invoke CMD? "REG" is just %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe; it's in PATH so you can invoke it straight from your C# code. That way you don't have to worry about passing a complex parameter through CMD's /C parameter. (At a guess, your problem is one of parameter escaping in CMD.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is well formed, and it isn't an escape code issue.

Likely you are hitting a UAC / privilege issue.

If you really want to go down this path rather than using the .NET registry API, I recommend you try the explicit form of creating a ProcessStartInfo and use Verb "runas" to get elevated privs.

```
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

The sure way to find out is to redirect IO and see what the process / shell is saying.

```
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

var child = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

You'll need to read from stderr / stdout (start a thread, or just for this case do it synchronously)

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((nRead = child.StandardError.Read(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE)) > 0)
    for (int n = 0; n < nRead; n++)
        sb.Append(buffer[n]);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Wow, this solution actually fixed similar problems in a couple other programs. having a way to throw the output buffer into a variable makes it easy peasy. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. I've actually got a reusable class for it, as well as a winforms component for logging the redirected IO out to a Window, or wrapping an arbitrary console program. It is certainly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Registry class. Even if you - for whatever reason - must use Process.Start it will help you debug your issue.

```
string key = @"HKCR\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolder";
string valueName = "Attributes";
string value ="0xA0900100";

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(key, valueName, value, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
```